Вылет программ после переноса Ubuntu в другой ПК
Всем доброго времени суток! Пол года назад я установил Ubuntu 24.04.4 на внешний SSD через ноутбук. Недавно у меня появился ПК. Я подключил диск с Ubuntu к нему, всё запустилось без проблем (загружал через Windows Boot Manager). Далее начались проблемы. Все программы, на первый взгляд, запускаются и работают нормально, но спустя некоторое время вылетают. К вылетающим программам относятся Firefox, PyCharm, IntellIjIDEA. Последние две откатывают все изменения при перезапуске.
Вот полный лог с момента запуска:
dertfin@dertfin:~/Desktop$ ./idea.sh 
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
2024-05-14 21:25:39,074 [    821]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.n.p.PersistentFSLoader - [VFS load problem]: VFS wasn't safely shut down: records.connectionStatus != SAFELY_CLOSED
2024-05-14 21:25:42,615 [   4362]   WARN - #c.i.o.v.n.p.PersistentFSLoader - [VFS load problem]: NOT_CLOSED_PROPERLY recovered, no problems remain
2024-05-14 21:25:42,693 [   4440]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.gradleJava.scripting.roots.GradleBuildRootDataSerializer <clinit> requests com.intellij.util.gist.storage.GistStorage instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-05-14 21:25:42,863 [   4610]   WARN - #c.i.i.s.p.i.BundledSharedIndexProvider - Bundled shared index is not found at: /home/dertfin/Apps/idea/jdk-shared-indexes
2024-05-14 21:25:51,654 [  13401]   WARN - #c.i.o.m.LanguageLevelUtil - File not found: api23.txt
2024-05-14 21:25:52,808 [  14555]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - No accessors for org.jetbrains.security.package.Package. This means that state class cannot be serialized properly. Please see https://jb.gg/ij-psoc
2024-05-14 21:25:54,623 [  16370]   WARN - #c.i.s.ComponentManagerImpl - com.almightyalpaca.jetbrains.plugins.discord.plugin.notifications.ProjectShowNotificationKt <clinit> requests com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginUtil instance. Class initialization must not depend on services. Consider using instance of the service on-demand instead.
2024-05-14 21:26:15,041 [  36788]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - No accessors for org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.arguments.InternalArgument. This means that state class cannot be serialized properly. Please see https://jb.gg/ij-psoc
2024-05-14 21:26:15,065 [  36812]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - No accessors for org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.projectConfiguration.KotlinNotConfiguredSuppressedModulesState. This means that state class cannot be serialized properly. Please see https://jb.gg/ij-psoc
2024-05-14 21:26:38,944 [  60691]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - No accessors for com.intellij.platform.feedback.impl.state.DontShowAgainFeedbackState. This means that state class cannot be serialized properly. Please see https://jb.gg/ij-psoc
2024-05-14 21:26:38,945 [  60692]   WARN - #c.i.u.x.Binding - No accessors for com.intellij.platform.feedback.impl.state.CommonFeedbackSurveysState. This means that state class cannot be serialized properly. Please see https://jb.gg/ij-psoc


а что железо одинаковое? Совсем уж такое?

Логичный вопрос - с какими ошибками вылетают?

Добавил логи в вопрос
